# put text at specific position on graphic matlab

Tags: matlab

let us consider following code :

```
step=3;
    sigma=-150:step:150;  
    TrMax=-((a1+sigma).^2)/(4*k1);
    % find position where Trmax is  equal to  minimum(possible zero)
    posmin = find(TrMax==min(TrMax));
  % fprintf('minimum of TrMax accurs at: %2.f\n',posmax)
  % fprintf('minimum of Trmax equal : %f', TrMax(posmax))
   %%  find value of sigma 
   minimum_sigma=sigma(posmin);
   %fprintf(' value of sigma where  Trmax=minimum is at %f',minimum_sigma)
       figure;
   % plot(sigma,TrMax);%Trmax as a function of Sigma
    plot(sigma(posmin:end),TrMax(posmin:end));%Trmax as a function of Sigma
    xlabel('Indirect Resultant');
    ylabel('Max of Total Revenue ');
    title(' Dependabce between Resultant and Total Revenue');
    grid on;
      text(sigma(posmin),TrMax((posmin),'\leftarrow TrMax=0'))
    xlabel('Indirect Resultant');
    ylabel('Max of Total Revenue ');
    title(' Dependabce between Resultant and Total Revenue');
    grid on;
```

result of the given code as  a figure is

[image]

what i want  is following : at position where  TrMax is equal to minimum  put  text,  i found  this position using

```
posmin = find(TrMax==min(TrMax));
```

i found also corresponding value of sigma

```
minimum_sigma=sigma(posmin);
```

but when i run program, i got following error :

```
Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 1).

Error in optimal_estimation_new_exp_2 (line 107)
      text(sigma(posmin),TrMax((posmin),'\leftarrow TrMax=0'))
```

i can't guess from where comes such error, please help me to solve this problem

Comment: `find(X==min(X))` in unrecommended, instead, use `[Val, Pos] = min(X)`. (same for `max`, `mean` etc.)

Comment: what about problem statement?  i think  everything should be correct right? i can't get reason of problem occurence

Answer (score 1):

That confusing message is just because you put the parenthesis wrongly:

```
text(sigma(posmin),TrMax((posmin),'\leftarrow TrMax=0'))
```

change to:

```
text(sigma(posmin),TrMax(posmin),'\leftarrow TrMax=0')
```

The first one is being interpreted as `TrMax(posmin, ASCII)` and its confusing MATLAB, as the ASCII values of those characters are more than 1, but your array only has 1 of size.

You can test this with:

```
a=magic(256);
a(1,'abc')
```

this returns the same as

```
a(1,[97 98 99])
```

Yes, confusing, and with unclear errors

Comment: @datodatuashvili I generally just hand-insert a bit of offset to the coordinates given.